# Does <img src=""> hurt performance?

Tags: asp.net, html

I just wanted to know if `<img src="">` hurts performance in asp.net? If yes, then how, and what is a better solution?

**EDIT**

I would like to add some more details:-If developer miss the src tag or if the image is missing from the server(for example a.jpg is missing from the server)

```
<img src="Images/a.jpg">
```

**EDIT**

I asked this question because recently I faced a problem in which our Page do double postaback just because of fav.ico was missing from the server.

Comment: Please try to add some more detail to your question.  What about `<img src="">` are you thinking might hurt performance?  This is the standard way of including images on a web page, so I'm not sure what the alternative would be.

Comment: @optus: Does he mean leaving it empty possibly?

Comment: If you mean an empty `src` attribute, see: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/

Comment: I think you need more information in to why you think this will hurt performance, and this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with ASP.NET since you are only talking HTML.

Comment: @Nick:I have updated my question.

Comment: Please notice FavIco requests are built in the browser and not related to img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you need another request to get the image. ;-)

IE6 won't respect content expiration headers when `<img>` is inside iframe.

It may be better to use a background image (CSS) with a sprite.